# ArcObjects Add-in closes ArcMap when JFrame is closed

Tags: java, jframe, arcgis, arcmap, arcobjects

My Add-in opens a new frame for user input. When this frame is closed, ArcMap also closes. I have the DefaultCloseOperation set to DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE.

My code inside the add-in button creates an instance of my GUI class.

```
public void onClick() throws IOException, AutomationException {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createGUI();
        }
    });
```

Any Ideas? I want the user to be able to exit the window normally and continue working in ArcMap.

Comment: The behavior seems to be due to exception handling. Once I finished my add-in and handled exceptions inside it, the frames close properly.

I also suspect the debug console I was using may have been calling System.exit() on it's close. That is a likely source of the behavior too.

It's solved now anyway.